# Animating drop shadow fade-in/fade-out with a storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, dropshadow

I'd like to fade in a drop shadow effect on a DataGrid over 2 seconds, which fades out over 2 seconds again after the fade-in animation is completed.

My code so far:

```
DropShadowEffect dropShadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect();
dropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 0;
dropShadowEffect.Color = Colors.LightSeaGreen;
dropShadowEffect.Opacity = 0;
dropShadowEffect.BlurRadius = 20;
element.Effect = dropShadowEffect;

Storyboard storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
TimeSpan duration1 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

DoubleAnimation animateOpacity1 = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1, Duration = new Duration(duration1) };
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animateOpacity1, element.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateOpacity1, new PropertyPath(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty));

DoubleAnimation animateOpacity2 = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 1, To = 0, Duration = new Duration(duration1) };
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animateOpacity2, element.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateOpacity2, new PropertyPath(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty));

storyboard1.Children.Add(animateOpacity1);
storyboard1.Children.Add(animateOpacity2);

storyboard1.Begin(element);
```

Upon executing the code, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to do DoubleAnimation, no need to complex it using StoryBoard. Also, you can achieve this with only single double animation with property **`AutoReverse`** set to **`true`**.

Moreover, ***do animation on dropShadowEffect object instead of element object***.

```
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

DoubleAnimation animateOpacity = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1,
                                     Duration = duration, AutoReverse = true };

dropShadowEffect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty,
                                animateOpacity);
```